# How to get current date and time in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, tridion

I am using xslt 1.0, I am trying to print current date and time to my node. Below is the sample xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:em="http://www.emirates.com/tridion/schemas" xmlns:tcmse="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/TcmScriptAssistant" exclude-result-prefixes="em xlink tcmse tcm">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Common XSLT Templates-->
  <xsl:include href="tcm:228-190524-2048"/>
  <!-- root match-->
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <sitedata>
      <resources>        
        <PublishedDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="$publishedDate"/>
        </PublishedDate>
      </resources>     
    </sitedata>
  </xsl:template>
```

In above XSLT, in the place of **$publishedDate** I want system current date and time

please suggest!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 does not provide any standard way to get the current date/time. You can call an extension function to do it (depends on your processor), or you can pass it to the stylesheet as the value of a parameter.

Comment: I tried to call xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times", but my xslt is giving error about this preposser, can you please help me on this!!

Comment: Follow this : http://www.exslt.org/howto.html. Also without knowing your xslt processor and without any specific code example we cannot help you further.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to know my XSLT processor, I mean where I can get that details?

Comment: What is your os? How are you transforming your .xml?

Comment: @Manu: You must read the documentation of your XSLT processor -- how to pass parameters to the XSLT transformation. Say which is your XSLT processor -- if it is wellknown, chances are many people already know how to do this.

Comment: @Manu chances are that you are using  Microsoft® XSL processor.

Comment: ok if I am using Microsoft XSL Processor, what will be the solution

Comment: If you are stuck with Microsoft then you are better of passing the date time as an argument via a parameter. The othet solution would be to implement the function yourself. Usage: MSXSL source stylesheet [options] [param=value...] here you can pass your parameter.

In your xsl stylesheet you will have to declare the parameter at the top level of your document and then simply use it where you want. 

<xsl:param name="date-time" required="yes"></xsl:param>

Comment: @Manu: Microsoft has at least three different XSLT processors. Which one are you using: MSXML3/4/6, .NET XslTransform or .NET XslCompiledTransform. The way of programmatically passing parameters to the transformation is different for the MSXML XSLT processors and the .NET XSLT processors.

Comment: @Manu, if you would tell us how you run XSLT, that would give us a lot more insight into what processor you're running.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how to do this with the [msxsl.exe command-line utility](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21714)** (for MSXML):

**XSLT code (testParams.xsl)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="vDate" select="xyz"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  "<xsl:value-of select="$vDate"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML document (t.xml)** (fake, ignored):

```
<t/>
```

**Command-line**:

```
msxsl t.xml testParams.xsl -o con vDate='%date%'
```

**Result**:

```
"Sun 10/02/2011"
```